# Html.EditorForModel() is returning blank screen as razor is not recognizing the `Object.cshtml` template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to utilize the `Html.EditorForModel()` to clean up my models.

I created different EditorTemplate for different data types. and when I user `@EditorFor()` everything seems to be good.

Now, instead of having to replicate the following multiple times in my form, I want to utilize the `Object.cshtml` editor template to do that for me.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(...)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(...)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a view in the EditorTemplates folder called "Object.cshtml` and I put the following code in it

```
@model dynamic

@{
    var elements = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(metadata => metadata.ShowForEdit && !metadata.IsComplexType && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata));
}
@foreach (var element in elements)
{
    if (element.TemplateHint == "HiddenInput")
    {
        @Html.Hidden(element.PropertyName)
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label(element.PropertyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Editor(element.PropertyName)
                @Html.BootstrapValidationMessage(element.PropertyName)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

How I replace the body of my form with  `@Html.EditorForModel()` but unfortunately I get a blank form.

I tried to put a break point in the `Object.cshtml` view but it never reach it. How can I make `Razor` aware of my `Object.cshtml`

Comment: Would need to test your code, but I suspect you might be executing the code on line 291 of the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for input here. At what point I could be excluding the `if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(fieldType))` line

Comment: Sorry - I do not understand - are you looking at the source code I liked to - the `if (html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData.TemplateInfo.VisitedObjects.Contains(visitedObjectsKey)) { return String.Empty; }`?

Comment: line 291, :) (your comment relates to line 191)

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the correction :)   if you look at my code, I am eliminating the visited objects `!ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata)` Not sure if I may be missing your advise here

Comment: That is why I said I would need to test it :) - but unfortunately I do not have the source code on this device to debug it

Comment: I see. When I try to debug the `Object.cshtml` code I code is never reached at the break point never used. so it is making it hard for me to debug it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166500/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mike-a).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I figure out the cause of this issue. Since I am accepting `dynamic` model in my `Object.cshtml` that seems to have caused razor to route incorrectly. So when I changed `@Html.EditorForModel()` to `@Html.EditorForModel("Object")` as expected.